# Possible to access ISE as storage?

Tags: cisco-ise, tftp

Is it perhaps somehow possible to access ISE's internal storage with software like WinSCP?

From what I see you can only use external servers to upload stuff from ISE onto but how about using ISE itself as an FTP/SCP server?

(The only reason I'm asking a seemingly silly question like this is because our customer doesn't have any permanent FTP solution available, so we're forced to beg some of their more friendly end users to e.g.: upload a certain file to one of their computers, install and enable Tftpd64 on it and leave it online for us for a few hours - so hardly an optimal solution for any remote network engineer)

Comment: I've never tried doing something like that, but I suspect it will be difficult if not impossible.  Cisco limits the functionality of the OS to keep it secure and prevent users from accidentally breaking it.  You're trying to do something they specifically don't want you to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While ISE includes FTP and SFTP clients, there's no FTP or SFTP server nor any support for SCP at all.